# Update object from two different database tables

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables in two different SQL Server databases on different servers. Each table has the identical number of rows (each ~65000) and they are related by a common `ID` column. I created an object that has properties read and updated from these two tables.

I read all items from first table and create an instance of my object and then update properties of it. Then I add it into a List. After this is done I read from second table in order to update remaining properties of the object.

What can be the best way to do this? Do you have suggestions? At this moment I loop through my List and for each object in the list get data from the second server. Of course this is consuming time (~15 minutes).

For example is it possible to create a temporary table on one of the servers? The time I consume is in my loop. Time spent while retrieving data from these two servers are OK for me.

Comment: First of all fill both database tables into two System.Data.DataTable variables and use Linq query to join them using your id column. Then you can go through the records and avoid calls to second db for each and every record.

Comment: @Indikaf I already get data from the servers first, sorry that this may not be clear in my explanation. When I measure time that is used to get SQL data I see that it is OK in my case. I have to spend most of the time when I try to find my object in the collection by Linq to set its properties according to Data table from the second server. Linked server approach seems to be convenient for me. Because I think I can do the same with what I do by Linq in my SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to create a linked server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Using this method, you can reference a database from a different server as if it were on the same server.  This should allow you to do a join to complete your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to add one of the servers as a linked server using [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) then you can run your query against one of the servers (joining both tables by the common field) and get everything in one shot.